# About sphatik Mala

Tags: japamala

1. I have a sphatik Mala of 107 +1 beads. Can I wear this  mala?
2. Can I remove sumeru with other sphatik beads to correct number ?
   or,  I have my old sphatik Mala  but  I don't know whether it is original or not. Can I add one beads from my old mala to current mala. So do the same.  I want remove my sumeru with old beads.

Answer (score 3):

1) Mala for chanting has to have 108 beads + 1 sumeru (for *grihasthi*). Keeping this in mind, you may add a sumeru.
Sumeru has to be there. While chanting a mantra, do not cross sumeru. After reaching upto sumeru, reverse the mala and continue. (reference:- '*Nitya Karma Pooja Prakash*' by *Geetapress, Gorakhpur* -- *Mala Prakarana*).
For this purpose, sumeru has to be prominent (you may add a larger bead).

2) If you wish to chant a mantra on mala, do not wear it. It has to be kept separate.

3) For identifying genuine & fake sphatik, I know one test. Press complete sphatik mala on your forearm (on the side w/o hair). Original would feel slightly colder, but fake would not. There may be other tests which I do not know.

HTH

Comment: This is true .. the scriptures state "Meru na ulanghayeth"